# New laptop battery inconsistent

Tags: laptop, windows-vista, battery, dell-vostro

I have a fairly old Dell Vostro 1510 laptop and the battery finally gave up recently. I bought another one on Amazon three weeks ago and, initially, it seemed to be OK: it was charging to 100% and going for a couple of hours before discharging. I went through the calibration process recommended in the instructions but, in the past week, have been finding that the battery icon does not seem to be giving a true indication of the battery status and the computer will suddenly shut down when I thought there was still a large percentage available.  At the moment, it is plugged into the mains, showing 33% but, for some reason, not charging. The Dell Battery says it is working normally, has 33% charge but is idle. Is this a problem with the battery or the laptop?  I could send the battery back but don't want to do this if it is not faulty.  I only use the computer for admin stuff and internet use, no heavy gaming, videos etc.

Comment: Sounds like a bad cell/pack. Good cells go rather steadily from ~4.1v down to 3.7v where they are dead, dodgy cells may go from 4.1 to 3.9 steadily then drop way down below the critical voltage that the laptop requires.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command you can use on your computer to extract extra information about your battery:

- Open an elevated command prompt and navigate to the folder you want
  to create your file, for example `cd %userprofile% /Desktop`
- Next, enter this command: `Powercfg -energy`

You'll now see a file on your dekstop called `energy-report.html`

From that file, you will be able to extract a lot of usefull information about not only the battery, but also general energy schemes on your computer.

Especially this section might be interesting (last 2 sets of data indicate the original capacity and the capacity that's been charged the last time):

[image: Accu data]

Comment: Thanks for your helpful advice.  I have now requested a return/refund so hope that will be accepted but then have to find a new battery that works satisfactorily without having to pay the full Dell price!